# Selenium can't access web-element by it's id (python)

Tags: python, selenium

I've wrote a simple selenium script to login to our system but selenium webdriver can't find any elements that are mentioned in the script.Elemnts have thew id of "username" and "password".There is one strange thing - this script works sometimes without any mistakes and sometimes i get the same error(while script isn't changing) .I'm running this script on windows 7 script was written with python 3.4 (maybe that's important)
Here is the code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class SodexoLogin(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_log_to_system(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://dev.itsoft.co.il:8080/dev/sodexo-backoffice-components")
        username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
        username.send_keys("*********")
        password.send_keys("*********")
        username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

HTML code for the elements looks like this:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" id="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
```

And here is the error message I get:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_log_to_system (__main__.SodexoLogin)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AT\test1.py", line 13, in test_log_to_system
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 234, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"username"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/TEMP/tmp_p25io7i/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10659)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///C:/TEMP/tmp_p25io7i/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10668)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///C:/TEMP/tmp_p25io7i/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///C:/TEMP/tmp_p25io7i/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/TEMP/tmp_p25io7i/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 9.957s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: can you post the html? at least the parts you are trying to find.

Comment: @drkthng Here is one of those elements - `<input type="password" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" id="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna explicitly wait for the elements themselves:

```
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui    

...

def test_log_to_system(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://dev.itsoft.co.il:8080/dev/sodexo-backoffice-components")
        wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id('username'))
        username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
        wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id('password'))
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
```

In my personal opinion this is a better approach to the implicit wait, because the latter will slow you down the whole time, while the specific waiting for certain elements only adds time to the script running at this specific point.

Comment: Thanks this approach is  more interesting and useful

Comment: But when i run this - i get this error message :ERROR: test_log_to_system (__main__.SodexoLogin)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AT\test2.py", line 13, in test_log_to_system
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10)
NameError: name 'ui' is not defined

Comment: @KirillAlexeyenko -> see my updated answer -> ui needs to stay, but the import line needs to be inserted at the top of your code. Try this and tell me how it worked out

Comment: yeah,sry,didn't mentioned that import, all works now)

Answer (score 1):

It seem to be the website haven't fully loaded.

Maybe you can add the implicit wait to it.

Just add  `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` after `driver = self.driver`

Comment: Well I've added your code - and I've received the next error - `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/AT/test2.py", line 13, in test_log_to_system
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'manage' `

Comment: Sorry, i have used the java code in the first comment. the updated version should be compilable

Answer (score -1):

This should fix it

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Comment: Kit's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34175923/369450) already says to do this.